# Can this task be solved more efficiently?

Tags: linear-programming, matlab

The following task is to write a little program to make a $5\times 9$-matrix that consists of the elements from 1 till 9 for each row. However each row has the power $+1$ of the previous row untill the $power = 5$ . So,

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
1^2 & 2^2 & 3^2 & 4^2 & 5^2 & 6^2 & 7^2 & 8^2 & 9^2\\
1^3 & 2^3 & 3^3 & 4^3 & 5^3 & 6^3 & 7^3 & 8^3 & 9^3\\
1^4 & 2^4 & 3^4 & 4^4 & 5^4 & 6^4 & 7^4 & 8^4 & 9^4\\
1^5 & 2^5 & 3^5 & 4^5 & 5^5 & 6^5 & 7^5 & 8^5 & 9^5\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

My approach was just to input the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$ of each row to the power that was needed and I felt like that was most efficient (by this I mean with the least amount of code) way to program it without using for, while or if- else-constructions. But I still think there is a more efficient way to do it directly without using the previously mentioned constructions.

> Anyone any ideas?

Comment: in PARI/GP that's matrix(9,9,i,j,j^i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the language you're using, but you can at least improve things slightly, by computing the entries of row $k$ by taking those of row $k-1$ and multiplying them by $\pmatrix{1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9}$. This lets you compute the fifth row with just 9 multiplies, rather than $9 \cdot 4$ multiplies.

If multiplication is an expensive operation, then this is a win; then again, if fetching an entry of an array is an expensive operation, then it's not.

If you were doing to same thing for a $5000 \times 9$ matrix, I'd expect my method to be honestly more efficient: in each column, instead of doing a total of $4999 \cdot 50000/2$ multiplies, I'd do only $4999$. That would probably outweigh the cost of the $4999$ fetches, And as the number of rows grows larger, the number of multiples in the naive approach increases quadratically, while the number of fetches in the fancier approach increases only linearly, so for *some* matrix height, the fancy method will end up definitely being better.

Comment: As I've written in the tag bar I'm using Matlab 2016a

Comment: Y'know...I'm going to suggest that if you want help, you should make it easy for people who are going to do the work for you. That includes giving clear definitions and constraints. For questions like yours, I never even look at the tags, because novices often include things like "number theory" on problems like these. If you said "In Matlab, I'm doing ABC.; is there a simpler way to express this?", you'd get one answer, and it might be the one you want. But you asked about efficiency, which to a computer scientist means operation counting, not "how much time it takes me to type this."

Comment: Your answer was what I was looking for but you wanted to know what language I used, right or was it more  in a retorical way?

Comment: Thx for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

You apparently want a matlab programming answer, so here goes:

```
[u,v] = ndgrid(1:5, 1:9); 
A = arrayfun(@(i,j)j^i, u, v);
```

Is it more "efficient"? Without a clear description of what you might mean by "efficiency", that's unanswerable. It's certainly fewer characters of typing.

Comment: I meant typing the problem with the least amount of code as you said earlier. But your previous answer was helpful too. My aplogies for not being clear enough. I hope my edit is better now.

Comment: One remark shouldn't you to change i^j to j^i?

Comment: Yep...fixed. $$